# Template not found: admin

Tags: craft3

I've just tried setting up a project locally which we have deployed on a Laravel Forge server.

After I ran `composer install`, `craft setup`, and then `craft project-config/apply`

And try visiting my https://site.test/admin URL, setup through Valet.

I just get Template not found: admin

This doesn't really make sense because admin isn't a template right?

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Is it possible that you're using a different `cpTrigger`? Can you take a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Yes it was an incorrect url on CP_PANEL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CP_PANEL environment variable needs to be set to the same as your current Valet URL